# Overloading bitwise operator while using interface-based development

Tags: c#

Using C# 3.0, .NET 3.5

I have a need for an enumeration that is a little smarter than a simple number.  I have worked around this with static classes and properties, but one thing I am missing is the ability to use the enumeration like a bit flag without accessing a specfic properity.

For example this works:

```
public interface isomething
{
int value { get; }
}

public class something : isomething
{
public int value {get; private set;}

public somthing(int value)
{
this.value = value
}

public void DoSomething()
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}

public static class SuperEnum
{
public static isomething first = new something(1);
public static isomething second= new something(2);
}
```

Then execute something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue((SuperEnum.first.value | SuperEnum.second.value) == 3);
```

And you get a true.  But if I add this to the something class:

```
public static int operator | (something leftSide, isomething rightside)
{
return leftside.value | rightside.value
}
```

Then execute something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue((SuperEnum.first | SuperEnum.second) == 3);
```

I get a message that | operator can not used on the isomething type which sucks.

If I go with concrete types, I am fine, but that is going to cause problems in the future.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks, mark

Comment: Why would you possibly need this? It seems like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve. I think there is probably a better solution to the problem, but if the operator is important you can do it using an abstract class instead of interface:

```
public abstract class SomethingBase
{
    protected int value;

    protected SomethingBase(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static int operator |(SomethingBase leftSide, SomethingBase rightside)
    {
        return leftSide.value | rightside.value;
    }
}

public class Something : SomethingBase
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }

    public Something(int value) : base(value)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about using an abstract base class (and it will probably be the way to go if I do not get a better answer here), but I heard so many times from people, "don't burn your base class," so I was trying to find another way.

Comment: Can you mention implications of changing it to abstract class?

Comment: Deriving from an abstract means that, if I need to derive from something later because of some framework, I will have to derive it from the base class.  But because I can not see that happening any time in the near future (next iteration), the base class is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the fact that the `ISomething` interface doesn't declare the operator, and I'm not sure that you can make an operator a part of an interface contract. What sort of problems do you expect to be caused by using the concrete class?

Comment: From what I can tell from the compiler output, interfases can not have operators.  As for te he issue with concrete types is the fact that each of the "enumeration" members has the potential of having a different implementation of the methods (the "dosomething"s).  The "enumeration" will be populated at runtime from an IoC container with different types that meet the business need, and having a common interface or base class is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing binary math, it sounds like you are talking about a value. If you are talking about a value, an immutable concrete type would be a good choice (*perhaps* a `struct`, depending on the size). And if you have a concrete type, you can add a bespoke operator.

Alternatively you could add an `Or` method to the interface (or add an extension method to do the same), but this may involve the first operand choosing the concrete type... but then, I'm not sure what the interface is adding anyway.